# Read a .dat file in java and compare with Database table result

Tags: java, database

My Requirement is we get .dat files from developers, We need to verify if the .dat files and database table result are same

Sample .dat file looks like

3009706~~F18130000010~~R60629572~~0~~936~~1~~PA4~~PA3~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Y~~
3009712~~F18130000020~~R50160248~~0~~430~~1~~PA4~~PA3~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Y~~
3009723~~8062229458PM~~R99999999~~0~~439~~1~~PA4~~PA3~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Y~~
3009728~~8028190839PM~~R57884273~~0~~936~~1~~PA4~~PA3~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Y~~

Sample Database table

[image]

I need to read each row from .dat files, query the database with the first value which is primary key and compare the db result with the .dat file result. each column is separated by ~~ symbol. Like wise i need to compare all rows with database results.

Like wise i have many files. So one table one .dat file. Manual Comparison is taking hell lot of effort . Need to automate this process
Steps i am thinking is

1. take the count of rows in .dat file and compare with the count of database
2. Read row by row in data file and capture all the values and using primary key query the database table with that primary key to get the result.
3. Compare the result with the .dba file row. If the data is null in db, there is no entry in .dat file, ALso need to verify if ~~ is present for each column separation.

Please provide me any idea or code to start with in java

Thanks in Advance

Comment: _"Please provide me any idea or code to start with in java"_ - This type of question is extremely off-topic here. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read each string through loop and split each line by ~~ and after save into a List or an Array and Compare with db by Index wise.

```
    // Read File code line by line
    File file = new File("xyz.dat");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
        String[] str = line.split("~~");
        list.add(str);
    }

    // Traverse Code from List and Array
    for(String arr[] : list) {
        if(arr[1] == "") // write code as per your usage
    }
```

after this traverse List and compare with your database using String[] index.

Comment: Since files can likely be huge, loading all the data into memory may not be possible.

Comment: you can read file into small batches and store in db temp table and compare your data. after that drop table or delete data from table.

Comment: Better yet, process them as they are read, and don't store them at all.

Comment: Depending on type of database there are utilities to read structured data into temporary table and can compare each column from file with that of database. For ex: SQLSERVER has OPENROWSET utility , oracle has utl_file. If you can specify the database name and version i can provide exact fast and efficient scalable solution that would run smoothly irrespective of the volume of data.